# How to interpolate in Angular animation

Tags: angular, angular-animations

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let obj of mainData | keyvalue">
   <span [@animate]="states.{{obj.key}}">
      //////////////////////////////
   </span>
</ng-container>
```

I get an error saying that "Expected expression, got interpolation"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brackets `[]` expect a expression, e.g. something like `states.obj.key`, whereas on normal attributes you have to use interpolation `{{}}` to insert an expression.

I think what you meant to write is either

`[@animate]="states[obj.key]"`

or

`@animate="{{ states[obj.key] }}"`

Answer (score 1):

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let obj of mainData | keyvalue">
   <span [@animate]="states.{{obj.key}}">
        code
   </span>
</ng-container>

or

<ng-container *ngFor="let obj of mainData | keyvalue">
   <span [@animate]="states.[obj.key]">
        code
   </span>
</ng-container>
```